# CMS that sends forgotten password

Tags: php, security, content-management-system

I'm trying to document this behavior and was wondering if anyone knows of a CMS or blogging platform or forum software that sends you your password in the clear when you request it.

Comment: They had better not send you your password.

Comment: Are you trying to document this behavior so other people do it or trying to show a bad example of why people do it? I hope not the former.

Comment: Note that "sending password in cleartext" in most cases == "storing password in cleartext". Now, how many high-profile password breaches a la Gawker are necessary until people get the fact that storing passwords in plaintext is a Bad Thing? (see e.g. this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gawker#2010_Data_Breach_incident ) In 2011, in any organization worth its salt (pun not intended), creating Yet Another Site that stores passwords in the clear should be reason for termination on the grounds of complete cluelessness and/or carelessness.

Comment: @Piskvor So Gawker doesn't hash/salt their user passwords?

Comment: They stored it in slightly obfuscated plaintext (I hope they fixed that),allowing for "send me my forgotten password".Boom,now *someone* out there has all those passwords. Hint: most people re-use passwords, so theoretically you could be held liable if the passwords are stolen from your server, and used to break into other servers. If Joe X. Schmoe has the same password on your site as he has in his bank account, say hello to Joe's lawyers (this is indeed one of the worse-case situations; yes, that's what he gets for reusing passwords - but the courts don't have to agree with that).

Answer (score 3):

No,  this would be an indication that this software is vulnerable to [CWE-257](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/257.html) or [CWE-256](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/256.html).  In any case you would be 100% sure that whoever wrote it is an idiot.

Comment: So no examples of any idiots? I need just 1. I remember signing up for websites that sent me my lost password in the clear, but don't remember which.

Comment: @twitter yeah idk to be honest.